# Trying to find the differences between two columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

Hi I have two columns next to each other, I want to highlight the cells that do not equal each other
for example:

if A=/=B HIGHLIGHTED

B=/=A HIGHLIGHTED

Thank you

Comment: What did you already try? (Hint: Did you attemp to use conditional formatting)

Comment: I did but it's not highlighting correctly for some reason. I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: An easy and quick workaround if probably using an extra colomn. E.g with `if( A1=B1, "identical", "different") and then filter on that coloumn and manually colour the cells. It is a dirty hack which might be a solution if you only need to do this once. It is not a proper long term solution and hence not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub HighLighter()
    For i = 1 To 9999
        If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i, 2) Then Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    Next i
End Sub
```

Typical result:

[image]

Change the ***9999*** to suit your needs.